# Show column headers with "ls" command

Tags: ls

Does the ls command have any functionality to show the column headers for decoding what the columns are? I'm aware of the portion of support text that describes the columns in

```
info ls
```

Answer (score 2):

I've a function as below in my `~/.profile`, for the same reasons,

```
k(){
    { echo PERMS LINKS OWNER GROUP SIZE modMONTH modDATE modTIME NAME
    ls -l; } |
    column -t |
    grep -v "total"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was also asked on SO –
sharing [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471147/2811537) here as well:

[exa](https://the.exa.website/) is a replacement/enhancement for `ls`. If you pass on the arguments `-lh` with exa, it will include a header row printing the column names like so:

```
exa -lh
```

Example output:

```
Permissions Size User     Date Modified Name
.rwx------    19 username 29 Sep 11:25  dont_cra.sh
drw-r-----     - username 29 Sep 11:26  f1
.rw-r--r--@ 811k username 29 Sep 11:25  row_count.dat
.rw-r--r--    54 username 29 Sep 11:25  some_text.txt
```

You can set up an alias in .bashrc that replaces ls with exa.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

The `ls` command does not have any support for printing column headers. Any solution will require external processing of the results of the `ls` command.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the @Niranjan answer, taken from the man of `column` command:

```
EXAMPLES
           (printf "PERM LINKS OWNER GROUP SIZE MONTH DAY " ; \
           printf "HH:MM/YEAR NAME\n" ; \
           ls -l | sed 1d) | column -t
```